# how print count table sql in python

Tags: python, sql, mysql-python

im trying to print count table in python, im write this code:

```
count = cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s;" str(table))
print count
```

all print results is 1, (think 1 = true), how i can print the real result of my sql command ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must fetch the result:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
count = cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + str(table))
db.commit()
print cursor.fetchone()[0]
cursor.close()
```

Comment: count = (1332L,)

what is 1332L ?
i need number result !

Comment: `fetchone` returns a tuple. I've added `[0]` so you can print just the number.